# Android 6.0: setMyLocationEnabled not work

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Here my `fragment` snippet:

```
public class MapFragmentTab extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private MapView mapView;
    private View rootView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    int MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 10;

    private static final String TAG = MapFragmentTab.class.getName();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "onCreateView: savedInstanceState: " + AndroidUtil.bundle2String(savedInstanceState));
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_tab, container, false);
        init();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void init() {
        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    // Called immediately after onCreateView()
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ");
        googleMap = map;
        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "setUpMap: ");
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck();
        } else {
            enableMyLocation();
        }
    }

    private void marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck: requestPermissions");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            enableMyLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: ");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
    }

    private void enableMyLocation() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "enableMyLocation: ");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "setMyLocationEnabled = true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

On Android 4.3. when map show and when I click on My location
 `Button` (in right corner) the camera success show my location.
But on **Android 6.0** when I click on this `Button`, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

//    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
private GoogleMap googleMap;
//    private EditText et_address;
public static String TAG = MapActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Context context;
int MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    context = MapActivity.this;
    // Initial Map
    try {

        MapFragment mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    googleMap = map;

    setUpMap();

}

public void setUpMap() {
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck();

    } else {
        enableMyLocation();

    }
}


private void marshmallowGPSPremissionCheck() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && checkSelfPermission(
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestPermissions(
                new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
    } else {
        enableMyLocation();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        enableMyLocation();
    }else {
        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
        // functionality that depends on this permission.
    }
}

private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
}
```

This is xml file

```
<fragment

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: I update my fragment. But it's not help me. Toast show, but button not work.

Comment: I update code for display map with current location. i tested on Android 6.0 and it's working fine. Please check with your code.

Comment: I think you are not added support library. Also, You are using fragment so, replace "this" with getActivity().

Comment: I update my post with your code. Toast is show, but button My Location not work

Comment: I found the problem. On device was disable check my location. After I enable then as result button My Location is work!!!